# Matlab - trim array based on second column

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have arrays with two columns of data. The second column will start and end with an unknown number of zeros and I want to cut these rows from my array, leaving only the non-zero terms. (For clarity, I want to delete both the zero and the data in column one).

How do I go about doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Say you have

```
a = [1 0
     2 0
     3 1
     4 6
     5 0
     6 9
     7 0
     8 0];
```

You can find the first and last non-zero elements (from the 2nd column) with

```
idx = a(:,2) ~= 0;
first = find(idx,1);    
last  = find(idx,1,'last');
```

Then remove rows before and after

```
b = a(first:last,:);
```

In this example, the zero in the middle is left untouched by the trimming (unlike if we'd done `b = a(a(:,2)~=0,:)`), and you get

```
b = [3 1
     4 6
     5 0
     6 9]
```